# Developing and Publishing an Office 365 app

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I'm considering developing an Office 365 mail app for public use and I'm looking for other apps on Office Store. But there are not so many apps out there. Why? Am I looking at the wrong place (http://office.microsoft.com)?

Answer (score 1):

*Pre-answer-disclaimer: I currently work for the Office Developer Platform team at Microsoft and therefore my answer here may be a little biased ;)*

Have you checked out the [Outlook apps in the Office Store](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps-for-outlook-FX102804983.aspx)? A comprehensive list of publically accessible mail apps can be found there. Keep in mind that not all mail apps created are found in the store - the platform allows for developers to create apps for internal use and so not all mail apps that exist are listed in the store. Regardless, Outlook/OWA is where many Office users spend most of their time -- it's a great venue for developing an app for Office.

Are you looking for example apps for ideas for development or for something else? Perhaps I can point you in the right direction towards the information you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the link you provided. I was expecting a ton of apps like in other stores but I guess many apps are for internal use just like you said.